# Does a borrower-lender / borrower-bailor have a claim against his borrower/bailee?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, borrowing, shomrim-bailees

If a *shoel* (someone who borrowed non-fungible personalty) re-lent the borrowed item to a further borrower (which he may not do), the original borrower (i.e., the relender) is liable to the original lender for any damages that occur. (*Shulchan Aruch*, *Choshen Mishpat* 342, q.v.)

Does the relender then have a claim against his borrower for those damages? (Assume the item was not *mesa mechamas m'lachtah*. In a normal case of borrowing, not reborrowing, the lender would have a claim against the borrower.)

Likewise, suppose the original *shoel* gave the item to a *shomer chinam* (bailee). Again, the borrower is liable for damages to the lender, even if the *shomer* was negligent (*poshea*). (Or at least so it seems to me. For one thing, it's directly analogous to the above case. For another, it's pretty much implied by *SA CM* 72:31, which doesn't say it's referring to only a case in which the bailee was not *poshea* (and the *nos'e kelim* don't say so, either).)

If the *shomer* was negligent, does the borrower have a claim against him? (In a normal case of bailment, not of a borrowed object, the bailor has a claim against the bailee for negligence.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch CM 396:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9733&st=&pgnum=430) says (my own loose translation):

> מסרו השומר לשומר אחר, והיזק - חייב; ששומר שמסר לשומר חייב. אפילו שומר
>   חנם שמסר לשומר שכר, ואם הזיק - חייב השומר הראשון לשלם לניזק **וילך לעשות
>   דין עם השומר השני.**
>
> If a *shomer* gave the item to a second *shomer* and it was damaged - he is responsible; as the rule is that, "A *shomer* who gives over the item to another *shomer* is responsible". This is the case even if *shomer chinam* gave the item to a *shomer sachar* [thus resulting in a higher level of care for the object]. If the item became damaged the original *shomer* must pay the owner, **and he must take it up with the second *shomer***.

This Halacha is also brought in [291:26](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9733&st=&pgnum=246), where from the context it is clear that *shomer* is not limited to a *shomer chinam/sachar* but includes a *sho'el*. The way the Halacha is summarized/explained in Pischei Choshen (Pikadon Vesha'ala Chapter 2 Seif 30) is as follows: If a *shomer* gives the item to a second *shomer*; if he was authorized to do so the owner deals with the second *shomer*, if he was not authorized to do so - the owner deals with the first *shomer*, and the first *shomer* deals with the second *shomer*.